# Angular2 Routing in conjunction to Express routing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, angular, typescript

My angular2 app's routes don't work when accessed via URL... Express is rendering an error page instead.

So I have one route (`/docs`) which serves some static content and some other static resources, however, `/` is routed to an index.html which is managed by angular 2. So by opening the application root and then clicking various router links I can get to a route e.g. `/tutorial/chapter/1`. However, as that isn't a registered route in my express app, if I refresh the page I get a 404.

I want to be able to type `http://localhost:3000/tutorial/chapter/1` into my browser and get that page. How do I set express to route all undefined routes to angular, and let angular handle the 404?

Here is my **app.js**:

```
var app = express();

// html view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/ng2/views'));
app.engine('html', require('jade').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(express.static('ng2/views'));
app.use(express.static('ng2/public'));

app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));    

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'ng2/public', 'favicon.png')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

//all static assetes for hexo content

app.use('/docs', serveStatic('features/docs/public', { 'index': ['index.html', 'index.htm'] }));

app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});


module.exports = app;
```

You can see the full repo [here](https://github.com/georgeedwards/docs/tree/noXSS)

Here is the routes middleware def:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**app.js**

Since order is important and new code is inserted in multiple locations, the whole file is included. Look for comment started with `// JS -`

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')
var file = require('./features/prepareTutorial');
var routes = require('./ng2/routes/index');

var app = express();

// html view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/ng2/views'));
app.engine('html', require('jade').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(express.static('ng2/views'));
app.use(express.static('ng2/public'));

app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
app.use('/persist', express.static(__dirname + '/persist'));

// JS - Add /app
app.use('/app', express.static(__dirname + '/ng2/views/app'));

// I have to comment this line because it failed
//file.processTutorial(); //generate html rendered patches for tutorial steps
//file.genGit(); //generate git SHA
file.processChapters();

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'ng2/public', 'favicon.png')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

//all static assetes for hexo content

app.use('/docs', serveStatic('features/docs/public', { 'index': ['index.html', 'index.htm'] }));
//app.use(subdomain('docs', express.static('docs/public')));
app.use('/script', serveStatic('features/docs/public/script'));
app.use('/style', serveStatic('features/docs/public/style'));
app.use('/images', serveStatic('features/docs/public/images'));
app.use('/diff', serveStatic('features/tutorial/diffs'));
app.use('/git', serveStatic('features/git'));
app.use('/chapter', serveStatic('ng2/views/app/tutorial/chapter/chapters'));
app.use('/img', serveStatic('features/docs/source/img'));

app.use('/config', serveStatic('ng2/config'));

app.use('/', routes);

// JS - /tutorial static
//app.use('/tutorial', express.static('ng2/views/app/tutorial'));
// JS - /tutorial/chapter/* send index file 
app.all(/^\/tutorial$/, (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/tutorial/');
});
app.use('/tutorial/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/ng2/views/index.html');
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

**ng2/config/systemjs.config.js & ng2/public/config/systemjs.config.js**

Use absolute path

This is the main issue. With relative path, the browser is requesting files at `tutorial/chapter/2/app/*`, `tutorial/chapter/2/node_modules/*`, etc, and the app break down completely.

```js
// snip ...
var map = {
    'app':                        '/app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   '/node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': '/node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       '/node_modules/rxjs'
  };
// snip ...
```

**ng2/views/index.html**

Use absolute path

This won't stop the page from loading but a mess.

```
// snip ...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
// snip ...
```

Comment: With that function, refreshing a working route doesn't load the page back, but it stays white and [this](http://imgur.com/a/ZrndK) is what the console says

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards you have relative path in your index.html when loading javascript. Post your index.html also so I can look at it.

Comment: Sure, see [here](https://github.com/georgeedwards/docs/blob/noXSS/ng2/views/index.html)

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Updated. Let me know if that works. I modified base on your ng2/routes/index.js. But I can't test as your git clone is give issue when I do `node app.js`

Comment: I am afraid not. I have push my current working version of the repo, so if you clone that (noXSS branch) and then try `tsc` then `node ./bin/www` or `nodemon ./bin/www` from the project route, that should work.

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards I checked the req/res url and seems they are really messy in router mode. The simple solution above will not work. Have to spend more time.

Comment: OK, thanks so much. Look forward to hearing your ideas.

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Fixed!!

Comment: I am afraid those modifications don't seem to work for me?  If you've done it in the git repo, maybe you could push a PR so I can see the difference? Currently, if I go to the tutorial path and then refresh I get the error page, despite having made all the modifications above.

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards PR created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121846/discussion-between-john-siu-and-george-edwards).

Answer (score 12):

Angular 2 assumes that independent of the request URL, the frontend will be returned. This assumption is based on a feature modern browsers implement called `push state`. You have 3 options if you want to support anything but the bleeding edge of browsers:

- **Recommended:** Seperate the API server from the client.
  If you put your client on `example.org` and your express backend on `api.example.org` you can just do what Angular assumes to be true. You can also deploy independently and the client can live on a static host or CDN. This will require that you setup CORS though.
- Catch-All Express Route
  Make sure all your routes in Express differ from the ones you setup in NG2 and make a catch-all handler. Put something like this **at the end of your routes/middleware** but before the 404 handler!

  ```
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile("index.html");
  })
  ```
- Use legacy browser-url-styles for the router.
  You can make the NG2 router use hashes for routes. Check [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so what would option 1 actually look like? I don't have any function aside from serving an ng2 app and some static content.

Comment: Then you're actually far better off without node! You don't need it for serving files, just for server-side processing. Just use a development web server for testing. I'd recommend [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/).

Comment: I have quite a lot of static node reliant processing going on to "generate" the site, e.g. using node fs API and npm packages to parse markdown etc. Would caddy still be best?

Comment: Actually, I think I am keen to keep my node backend as I have some future features planned which will require a backend API.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `app.use('/', routes);`, register a middleware that will always serve the `index.html`. Be cautious though, this can cause your app to return `index.html` even inside the `/docs` route.

Just use the middleware that renders the index page:

```
app.use(routes);
```

Make sure the `routes` middleware itself always renders the page, not only on `/` path.

```
var express = require('express');

/* render home page. */
var router = function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};

module.exports = router;
```

Remove this the 404 handler (it should be automatic)

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

And change the node_modules route to the following (because SystemJS relies on 404 responses during resolution):

```
var modules = express.Router();

modules.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
modules.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // Missing files inside node_modules must return 404
    // for the module loader to work
    res.sendStatus(404);
});


app.use('/node_modules', modules);
```

Comment: With this, I still get an error when directly routing to (for example) `http://localhost:3000/tutorial/chapter/0`, do I need to configure ng2 to support this in the router?

Comment: No, angular works dis way by default. So you say the server still returns 404? Are you sure that files are served from the doc folder correctly? And what is in your routes variable?

Comment: yes `http://localhost:3000/docs/` still works fine. If you look at the edit at the bottom of my question, the last snippet is imported as `routes`

Comment: This is the worst of the options, because collisions happen.

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards edited my answer. The thing is that the `router` route still filtered requests to the root path.

Comment: @Gant I partially agree with you, the more top level routes you have (static files, angular routes) the more chance a collision will occur. That's why I usually recommend to put all static content inside a `static` path, so the angular component only needs to make sure that it doesn't use routes starting with `/static/`

Comment: If I don that and refresh a working route, I get [this](http://imgur.com/ylqcBff) in my console?

Comment: It seems systemjs will load modules based on a trial and error logic, so it relies on some routes returning 404. I will update my answer in a moment.

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Updated my answer, lets see if it helps you

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I am afraid something still seems to be biting me. I still get the `0:1 Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token <` issue in my browser console.

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards It would help so much if you could tell me the path from where that file was taken by systemjs

Comment: @TamasHegedus I'm not sure what has gone on there, any way I could find out more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121767/discussion-between-george-edwards-and-tamas-hegedus).